# Transfering files from PC to ipad 3 with out using itunes

Tags: itunes, windows, ipad, file-transfer

Just got an Ipad3 and want to transfer files from PC/Win7 to Ipad 3 with out using Itunes.

Comment: What files and which app do you use to read them?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to iGameRam's answer, you can transfer files by either a [dropbox](http://dropbox.com/) or [iCloud](http://iCloud.com/) or other cloud solutions.  Depends on the file types and applications that you wish to use them with.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is like "can i transfer files from PC to iPad 3 without any software" then its a NO AFAIK. If its just to avoid iTunes then you can used [Disk Aid](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFQQFjAA&url=http://www.digidna.net/products/diskaid&ei=Gr76T-rlD9HQrQfH_K3HBg&usg=AFQjCNFqV8BjHQNC4zjU6_iSVq42HThEKg&sig2=JaqSTNAbDh6BxYuvNKqPQA) or similar softwares. Hope this answers your question.